# Error on sudo apt-get update, 404 Not Found , and error on sudo apt-get update in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, update-manager

I try to use Ubuntu 13.04 to run a specific project that works only on Ubuntu 13.04. I failed to get git and g++, so I tried [this one](https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/) and now I have problems with sudo apt-get update

Comment: [Ubuntu 13.04 is EOL, thus, not supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an LTS (long term support) version of Ubuntu, therefore updates and upgrades don't work after some years. 
for specific software you should search for a version that is compatible with ubuntu 13.04